# What to do if the clearicontap is executed after the change event in Extjs6?

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

Whether you click the clear icon in a field the change event is executed before the clearicontap event. This prevent the expected behavior.

According to this [2015 Sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299889-Textfield-clearicontap-event-fires-after-change-not-before) they detected the issue in order to find a solution but it is not solved.

**Live Example:**
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `onClearIconTap` method on textfield and fire new custom event there.

Check the example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2s4p

Comment: If my answer is correct, mark it as "This answer is useful" to let other people see that the question is solved.